# Passing a Boolean from one window to another

Tags: c#, wpf, boolean

I'm having two issues which I'm pretty sure are separate in WPF. First off boolean xs isn't getting passed into the Main Window which I've checked by testing where it is true and where it isn't. Also Cross 1 and Cross 2 do not draw if I add them to the Stack Panel in a button click event. Sorry about it being two pretty basic questions but I can't find anything that works. Also I tried to spare you guys as much reading as possible so if you need anything else to make it work for whatever reason don't hesitate to ask for it.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
        Rectangle Rectangle = new Rectangle();            
        Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown += Rectangle8_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        Rectangle Cross1 = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle Cross2 = new Rectangle();
        myStackPanel.Children.Add(Rectangle8);
        bool xs = Menu.Xs;
        bool os = Menu.Os;
        bool RectangleClicked = false;
        void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            RectangleClicked = true;
        }
        void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            RectangleClicked = true;
        }
        if (RectangleClicked == true)
        {
            myStackPanel.Children.Add(Cross2);
            myStackPanel.Children.Add(Cross1);
        }
        if (xs == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Xs is true");
        }
       }
    }
```

Window Two Code

```
public partial class Menu : Window
{
    public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static bool Xs { get; private set; }
    public static bool Os { get; private set; }
    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Xs = true;
        Os = false;
        this.Close();
    }

    public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Xs = false;
        Os = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Xs is false");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: have you tried setting the visibility of the crosses?

Comment: This code doesn't work. Where is the XAML? How does this compile   Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown += Rectangle8_MouseLeftButtonDown;?

Comment: @L0uis iv'e greatly abbreviated it the full compiled version helps i can send that.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/christheyankee/0b19581df7a8ba32cbfa4fdd5de80e86 full version

Comment: Yes @RickHodder

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with the Menu not returning the values:
You need an event to signal to main window that menu has closed and should retrieve the new values from menu.

In Menu, we add a delegate and event to signal that data has changed and the menu is closing:

```
public partial class Menu : Window
    {
        public delegate void DataChangeHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        // an instance of the delegate
        public DataChangeHandler DataChanged;
        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static bool Xs { get; private set; }
        public static bool Os { get; private set; }
        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Xs = true;
            Os = false;
            DataChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            this.Close();
        }

        public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Xs = false;
            Os = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Xs is false");
            DataChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());//when menu closes announce change event if a handler is wired up to listen.
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

In MainWindow, we have two properties for x and o's being set from menu. These are outside the constructor.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        bool xs;
        bool os;
        public MainWindow()


         {
    //snip
    Button Start = new Button();
                Start.Height = 50;
                Start.Width = 200;
                Start.Margin = new Thickness(500, -100, 0, 0);
                Start.Content = "Start";
                myStackPanel.Children.Add(Start);
                Start.Click += Start_Click;
                 xs = Menu.Xs;
                 os = Menu.Os; 
    }
     private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                  Menu win2 = new Menu();
                  win2.DataChanged += MenuClosed; //handler
                  win2.Show();

            }
            public void MenuClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) //fires after closing menu
            {
                xs = Menu.Xs; //get new values from Menu for x and o
                os = Menu.Os;
            }
```

The second issue:Cross 1 and Cross 2 do not draw if I add them to the Stack Panel.

You need create new crosses and add them to the desired rectangle. First remove the handler to the rectangle clicked outside the constructor in Mainwindow.

```
void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            RectangleClicked = true;
            HandleMove(); //draw a new cross either X or O to 'this' square
        }
```

For each rectangle you add, add a handler to draw the right cross inside the clicked rectangle. The cross drawing handler would then check if x's or o's are set and draw the right cross and add the cross to the rectangle.

Comment: I've tried following your advice for the crosses and I can't seem to get the handler to work. I'm probably misinterpreting you so if you would show a better example of what you mean maybe? @L0uis .